# Как ограничить количество постов для user до 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Чтобы он мог постить только 1 статью?

```
def index
   @restaurants = Restaurant.all
end
def new
   @restaurant = Restaurant.new
   render :layout => "users"
end
def show
   @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
end
def create
   @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)
   if @restaurant.save
     flash[:success] = 'Project was saved!'
     redirect_to root_path
   else
     render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мало информации. Что у вас сейчас в контроллере, как аутентифицируете пользователя, есть ли проверка прав в cancancan/pundit/аналогах.

Вот общее решение в лоб. В контроллере с постами напишите:

```
before_action :authorize_user_post_count, action: [:new, :create]

private

def authorize_user_post_count
  return unless current_user.posts.size > 0
  redirect_to 'some page', error: 'Вы не можете создавать более 1 поста'
end
```

Comment: "compared with non class/module"

Comment: У вас в вопросе про посты, а в коде про рестораны. Какая между ними связь?

Comment: Да я образно написал про посты чтобы понятнее было, так то одно и тоже

Comment: Понял, тогда подстраивайте код решения под свои нужды ;)

Comment: Ладно спасибо  буду подстраивать